# Mix https and http on single tomcat instance

Tags: apache, tomcat, protocols, server.xml

I have an application which in general works in https. Tomcat listens on port 8443:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keyAlias="MY_ALLIAS" keystoreFile="PATH_TO_MY_KEY"
           keystorePass="MY_PASWORD" />
```

Apache listens on 80 and redirects to 8443:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAlias localhost
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8443/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8443/
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Finally in web.xml there I added:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MY_WEB_RESOURCE_NAME</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Unfortunatly I have to add IFRAME with http site into one of my websites. Security is not a problem there. My problem is Tomcat configuration. I guess I will dispatch traffic with Apache. But now my question is how to setup Tomcat, so I can serve site http://localhost:8080/siteA and all the other sites will be served on https://localhost:8443/myOtherSites? I tried removing redirectPort="8443", but it's not enough. I'm using Tomcat 9.0.0.M4 (it's not a problem to move to Tomcat 8, if I would need to).
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Solve this problem add one more `<security-constraint>` tag in your web.xml like this `

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Unsecured resources</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/siteA</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint> `
```

Since you have set transport-guarantee as NONE , tomcat will not verify if its a secured resource or not . In this manner this `<security-constraint>` will help to access your `siteA` over http and the other`<security-constraint>` tag that you have already declared will help you access your other sites on `https`. Just remember in `<url-pattern>` tag give path to the pages that you want to keep as http or https  Let me know if this solves your problem :) .

Comment: you're Welcome, Happy to help  :)